# Copy values from an object array into a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following array of objects:

```
  names: [
    {
      "first": "Bob",
      "last": "Newhart"
    },
    {
      "first": "Jerry",
      "last": "Seinfeld"
    },
    {
      "first": "Oprah",
      "last": "Winfrey"
    }
  ]
```

I want to convert this into a simple array that looks like this:

```
names: [ "Bob Newhart", "Jerry Seinfeld", "Oprah Winfrey"]
```

What is the proper way to do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Try [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Try map operator

Comment: Google Map Reduce functions in javascript

Comment: Map is enough: `names=names.map(function(name) { return name.first + " " + name.last })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map each value and concatenate first and last name

```
names.map(obj => obj.first + ' ' + obj.last)
```

```js
var names = [{"first": "Bob","last": "Newhart"},{"first": "Jerry","last": "Seinfeld"},{"first": "Oprah","last": "Winfrey"}]
  
names = names.map(obj => obj.first + ' ' + obj.last)
  
console.log(names)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted?

Comment: To allow deletion of poorly researched question with answer in comments

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!